# syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in

Tags: if-statement, zend-framework

I would like to make an `endif` but I got an error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in

Who can fix this problem?

```html
  <div class="container">
                 <?php if ( isset($users_co_nbre) ) {
                    foreach ($users_co_nbre as $value): 
                  if($value["co_nbre"] <=10)?>
                  <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?= $value["co_nbre"]+5 ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?= $value["co_nbre"] ?>%">
                      <?= $value["first_name"] ?> <?= $value["last_name"] ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    
                  <?php if($value["co_nbre"]==20&&$value["co_nbre"] ==2)?>
                  <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?= $value["co_nbre"]+5 ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?= $value["co_nbre"] ?>%">
                      <?= $value["first_name"] ?> <?= $value["last_name"] ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest for clarity sake to enclose each control statement with php tags, ending with ":", thus your code slightly modified would work, as in:

```html
<html>
<div class="container">
  <?php $users_co_nbre = array(array('co_nbre'=>8, "first_name"=>'x', "last_name"=>'y'));?>
  <?php if ( isset($users_co_nbre) ) :?>
  <?php    foreach ($users_co_nbre as $value):?>
  <?php            if($value["co_nbre"] <=10):?>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?= $value[" co_nbre "]+5 ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?= $value[" co_nbre "] ?>%">
      <?= $value["first_name"] ?>
        <?= $value["last_name"] ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if($value["co_nbre"]==20 || $value["co_nbre"] ==2):?>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?= $value[" co_nbre "]+5 ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?= $value[" co_nbre "] ?>%">
      <?= $value["first_name"] ?>
        <?= $value["last_name"] ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi eyal. You state in your answer that you added the php tags for clarity. So what was actually wrong with the code posted by samer sboui? As it is, your answer is hard to understand for others who encounter that syntax error. Maybe you could clarify.

Comment: Mr Z - you're right, indeed it is not just clarity issue but actually the part that fixes the above code. As far as I'm aware when embedding PHP code  in html, each control statement should be enclosed with php tags - I have yet to see a counter example.